# Цвет номеров строк в Android studio

Tags: android-studio, настройка

Включил отображение номеров строк в Android Studio, по умолчанию они имеют красный цвет, что сильно бросается в глаза:

[номера строк в android-studio](http://storage9.static.itmages.ru/i/16/1230/h_1483092687_9595011_dd2fe0d2c5.png)

Как можно сделать их отображение таким же, как в IDEA?

[номера строк в IDEA](http://storage8.static.itmages.ru/i/16/1230/h_1483092676_2501465_80d50d0867.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сделать это можно тут:

> File > Settings > IDE Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > Line
>   Number.

Если цвет не меняется, ругаясь на "Read only" нажмите <kbd>Save As...</kbd> рядом с выпадающим списком "Scheme name".

Comment: На самом деле этот параметр находится здесь: `File > Settings > IDE Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General > Code > Line Number .`